# PhoneGap 2.7, BarcodeScanner : sharing barcodescanner.js for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use BarcodeScanner Plugin for my webapp with PhoneGap. It's a mobile application for iOS and Android. In my webapp on my server, I have html pages and javascript libraries.
I tried to share the *barcodescanner.js* on my server for my Android and iOS devices, but it doesn't work. I think it's not the same *barcodescanner.js* for iOS and Android.

**How can I use the same *barcodescanner.js* for all devices ? Or how can I use BarcodeScanner Plugin for all mobile OS (Android and iOS) on my webapp ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, the barcodescanner.js sources looks similar but do contain some subtle differences.  You can take a look at the sources here:
[PG Plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)

I recommend that you look into rather than using the same JavaScript Source file on your server for both devices to look into PhoneGap Build.  For example, in the config file, all you have to do to "inject" the Barcode Scanner plugin into your application is add `<gap:plugin name="BarcodeScanner" />` to the `config.xml`.  Then just use PhoneGap Build and it will build the application for all devices.  You can read more about it here: [PhoneGap Build Plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using).

**Update**
As mentioned in the comments below viable solution to the specific problem can be found [here](http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2011/12/12/Dynamically-loading-the-correct-PhoneGapjs-file-for-Android-or-iPhone).

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer !
Obviously PhoneGap Build make all your app : "We take care of all the packaging and compilation (...)".
But I would like to control the source of my app.

How to get the generated source code by PhoneGap Build to use it and compile it in Eclipse and XCode by myself ?
Or, how can i developp my app with the BarcodeScanner Plugin without PhoneGap Build ?

Comment: Well, by uploading your app to PhoneGap Build, that means you have already wrote all the source pages(items in the `www/` folder).  But if you want more control, follow the getting started guide found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides)
And then follow the instructions for implementing the Plugin [here](http://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner)

Comment: Thanks!!! I found an other solution: before calling the _barcodescanner.js_ file, I test the type of device and I call the correct _barcodescanner.js_ file.
See: [here](http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2011/12/12/Dynamically-loading-the-correct-PhoneGapjs-file-for-Android-or-iPhone)